# Create WebSphere Variable programatically in Java

Tags: websphere

I am writing Java code which creates the server resources required by the application. I have done it in Jython and I did it similarly in Java but its not working. I need the Java code to create websphere variable using the ConfigServiceProxy.

I tried 
1. configService.createConfigData(session, varMap, "VariableSubstitutionEntry", "VariableSubstitutionEntry",attributeList)

2. configService.createConfigData(session, varMap, "entries", "VariableSubstitutionEntry",attributeList)
3. Tried adding the websphere entry in VarMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following example code to create VariableSubstitutionEntry on Server level VariableMap:

1. ObjectName server = configService.resolve(session, "Node=" + nodeName + ":Server=" + serverName)[0];
2. ObjectName vm = ConfigServiceHelper.createObjectName(null, "VariableMap", null);
3. ObjectName[] vms = configService.queryConfigObjects(session, server, vm, null);
4. AttributeList attrList = new AttributeList();
   attrList.add(new Attribute("symbolicName", "WAS_SERVER_NAME"));
   attrList.add(new Attribute("value", "dmgr"));
5. ObjectName vse = configService.createConfigData(session, vms[0], "entries", "VariableSubstitutionEntry", attrList);

Comment: Thanks that helped, how do I update the value or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a VariableSubstitutionEntry, you can try the following code:

if (vms.length != 0) {
    ObjectName vm2 = ConfigServiceHelper.createObjectName(null, "VariableSubstitutionEntry", null);
    ObjectName[] vms2 = configService.queryConfigObjects(session, vms2[0], vm2, null);

```
for (int i = 0; i < vms2.length; i++) {
    ObjectName vse = vms2[i];
    String name = (String) configService.getAttribute(session, vse, "symbolicName");
    if (name.equals("WAS_SERVER_NAME")) {
        configService.deleteConfigData(session, vse);
        configService.save(session, false);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To update a value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vms2.length; i++) {
    ObjectName vse = vms2[i];
    String name = (String) configService.getAttribute(session, vse, "symbolicName");
    if (name.equals("WAS_SERVER_NAME")) {
        AttributeList newVal = new AttributeList();
        String newValue = "dmgr2";
        newVal.add(new Attribute("value", newValue));
        configService.setAttributes(session, vse, newVal);
        configService.save(session, false);
    }           
}
```